# Null pointer exception with configuration

Tags: java

This is my code. It thinks that the config area section = null.

Heres the code:

public void loadArenas() {

```
    fc1 = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "config.yaml");

    if (!fc1.exists()) {
        try {
            fc1.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    fc = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(fc1);

    for (String keys : fc.getConfigurationSection("Arenas.").getKeys(false)) {
```

Oh and heres the error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FvrA.jpg)

Comment: wich one is the line 224?

Comment: `It thinks that the config area section = null.` If there's an NPE, then it IS null. You shouldn't argue with the JVM, but find the source of the problem.

Comment: I suggest you print out the contents of fc or look at your file and verify whether that section exists. If the config file doesn't exist, you create a new one, but I don't see any sort of pre-populating going on. So if you DO create a new one, then I expect the section to not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`fc1` is initialized, but `fc` is not.

Comment: It all works. Fc is intialized but its the "getConfigurationSection"

Comment: @user3482764 so what is the problem? if you know what is null, why don't you fix your code?

Comment: I'm asking because I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @user3482764  Why do you think `getConfigurationSection` is the problem? Or rather, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Because thats where the npe leads to

Comment: @user3482764 The stacktrace only indicates that something on that line is null. How do you know it's `getConfigurationSection`?

Comment: Nevertheless, we can not see it properly because your code-fragment is stangely chosen.

Comment: Ill add numbers and lines

Comment: I reloaded the plugin and now its saying: fc1 = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "config.yml"); is the problem?

Comment: @user3482764 maybe you should post your `loadConfiguration();` function?

Comment: config.yml or config.yaml as posted in your question? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should print out the contents of `fc1` at the top. It is very likely that you are running into path-related issues and so a new, EMPTY, configuration file is created.

That new file is then used as the input to `fc`, and naturally the "Arenas." section wouldn't exist. The NPE would either be thrown when you try to access the non-existent section's keys via `getKeys()`.

Either way, if you are not sure what the problem is, you can either step through it with a debugger or just throw print statements everywhere to determine that things are what you expect.

Comment: I'll try add defaults :) Could you possibly give me the code to add the defaults please?

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. If you're always creating a fresh config file with default settings, that pretty much defeats the purpose of using a config file.

Comment: I'll try create the Defaults and if this works, you've saved me.

Comment: Doesn't work, still says the fc1 = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "config.yml"); is a problem :(((

Comment: I thought you said `getConfigurationSection` was the problem? Were you providing incorrect information the whole time?

Comment: It was, but I reloaded the plugin and now it just went to that

Comment: Then check your filenames. Or explain what the problem is.

Comment: I'll put in my best detail:

Comment: fc1 = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "config.yml");

  if (!fc1.exists()) {
   try {
    fc1.createNewFile();
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  fc = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(fc1);

  for (String keys : fc.getConfigurationSection("Arenas").getKeys(false)) { it says fc1 variable is null. So i possibly think it has something to do with the plugin variable but I definitely know its not null. I've printed stacktraces, I've made methods such as: public Manager(PParty pparty) {
  plugin = pparty;
 }